# How can I create a NSPopover out side my app

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nspopover

I have a requirement that I have to create a NSPopover on selected text at another app window. I am using below method, but I am confused what to placed positioningView

```
 - (void)showRelativeToRect:(NSRect)positioningRect ofView:(NSView *)positioningView preferredEdge:(NSRectEdge)preferredEdge;
```

Comment: You can always make your own (invisible) view for it, right?

Comment: You would need to display an invisible window over the desired text and then show the popover from there.